# R - Lists are same sizes but will not graph them

Tags: r

I have 2 lists both with length 911. When I try to plot them it says they are different lengths. I apologize I do not have enough reputation to post pictures in here so I put it on imgur. Here is a picture of what the error is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPmWm.jpg. Anyone know what could be happening?

Here is what it looks like:

```
print(length(m7Fluo))
[1] 911
print(length(m9Fluo))
[1] 911
plot(unlist(m7Fluo),unlist(m9Fluo))
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :  
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `unlist()`, you are concatenating all elements together.  If any element of the list has a length greater than 1, the length of the list (provided there are no NULL values) will be greater when unlisted.

For example

```
example = unlist(list(a = 1:3, b = 4))
```

The list has two elements, but when you call `unlist`, it becomes  the same as

```
c(1,2,3,4)
```

Check to see if you have any elements that are NULL or length greater than 1, and then deal with them appropriately.

Also, you can type code here by adding four spaces before the code starts on the line, keeping a blank line in between it and any other non-code text.

Comment: Ok thanks, ill try that. Ill mark as answer in a few mins when it lets me.